# R - How to set named value from data frame

Tags: r, variables

I have a data frame that currently stores multiple variables to be used through the remainder of my R script, example data frame structured as follows:

```
VarName  VarDefinition
VarA     1
VarB     2
```

Is it possible to loop through the table to define the named values VarA (equal to 1) and VarB (equal to 2) as per the details in the table?

Comment: It is possible. But why do you want to create multiple objects?

Comment: learn about the assign() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following helps your case:

```
> for(i in 1:nrow(varT)) {
    assign(paste(varT$Varname[i]), varT$VarDefinition[i])
  }

> VarA
[1] 1

> VarB
[1] 2
```